# How to sum radio button values using flash builder

Tags: ios, apache-flex, flash-builder

assuming i have 6 radio groups like:

```
<s:RadioButtonGroup id="radiogroup1"/>
<s:RadioButtonGroup id="radiogroup2"/>
<s:RadioButtonGroup id="radiogroup3"/>
<s:RadioButtonGroup id="radiogroup4"/>
<s:RadioButtonGroup id="radiogroup5"/>
<s:RadioButtonGroup id="radiogroup6"/>
```

How to sum radio button values using flash builder and to put some conditions like if score <10 - show a message(poor score) near the result ; if score>= 10(medium score)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        private function sumAll():void
        {
            var totalValue:Number;




            for each(var rbg:RadioButtonGroup in  [radiogroup1, radiogroup2, radiogroup3,radiogroup4, radiogroup5, radiogroup6])
            {
                totalValue+= rbg.selectedValue;  // if these are strings be sure to parseInt(rbg.selectedValue)
            }


            firstLabel.visible = firstLabel.includeInLayout = secondLabel.visible = secondLabel.includeInLayout = thirdLabel.visible = thirdLabel.includeInLayout = false;

            if(totalValue>10)
            {
                //Alert.show("You had more than 10");
                firstLabel.visible = firstLabel.includeInLayout = true;
            }
            else if(totalValue<=10 && totalValue>5)
            {
                //Alert.show("You passed");
                secondLabel.visible = secondLabel.includeInLayout = true;
            }
            else if(totalValue<=5)
            {
                //Alert.show("You failed");
                thirdLabel.visible = thirdLabel.includeInLayout = true;
            }
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<s:RadioButtonGroup id="radiogroup1"/>
<s:RadioButtonGroup id="radiogroup2"/>
<s:RadioButtonGroup id="radiogroup3"/>
<s:RadioButtonGroup id="radiogroup4"/>
<s:RadioButtonGroup id="radiogroup5"/>
<s:RadioButtonGroup id="radiogroup6"/>
<s:Label text="Winner winner chicken dinner" id="firstLabel" visible="false" includeInLayout="false"/>
<s:Label text="You passed" id="secondLabel" visible="false" includeInLayout="false"/>
<s:Label text="You failed" id="thirdLabel" visible="false" includeInLayout="false"/>
```

Comment: thanks a lot !but it shows me an error message on Alert , its undefined  property

Comment: can i make 3 labels that will load depending on score?!!

Comment: Yup showing or hiding labels should work fine too, I was sort pseudo-coding that one up within a Flex 3 project, I believe you should still have the same Alert method available, make sure you ctrl+space after the word Alert to get the auto-import... I'll modify with a label version shortly.

Comment: maybe import mx.component.Alert doesnt work for flash builder mobile project! i surprised too! i am testing this for IOS device

Comment: Yah I actually vaguely recall some issue with using Alert in certain Flex 4 apps, but like you're going for here I've always just worked around it using other UI controls, I don't have any really serious Flex 4 apps (mobile or not) just things I've toyed around with to be more familiar since I'm sorta stuck on Flex 3 with the long-term project I've been on.

Comment: here is the error that i get Description Resource Path Location Type
1120: Access of undefined property Alert. AuditView.mxml /credite1/src/views line 116 Flex Problem
1120: Access of undefined property Alert. AuditView.mxml /credite1/src/views line 121 Flex Problem
1120: Access of undefined property Alert. AuditView.mxml /credite1/src/views line 126 Flex Problem

Comment: @vicx have you tried just commenting out the Alert lines, since now you'll have the labels as indicators of the computed value now, I'll see if I can drop the code you posted in a fresh mobile project and get it to build/run too, what version of the Flex SDK are you using?

Comment: omg your are right i forgot that you put the labels there! i just tested and it returns nothing ! strange

Comment: As the other posted started you'll have to trigger the function somehow (click event handler or otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [CHANGE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/RadioButtonGroup.html#event%3achange) event to each `RadioButtonGroup` to be notified when the user changes the selection. In the event handler, sum up the values from the radio button group and act accordingly.

MXML:

```
<s:RadioButtonGroup id="radiogroup1" change="onRadioButtonChange"/>
<s:RadioButtonGroup id="radiogroup2" change="onRadioButtonChange"/>
```

Then in a script block:

```
private function onRadioButtonChange(event:Event):void
{
    var score:Number = 0;
    score += radioGroup1.selectedValue
    ...
}
```